# How is the 1GB dataset generated, which is used by the Ethash algorithm?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining, proof-of-work, ethash

I want to understand algorithmically how the 1GB dataset is generated and how it is updated based on block data in Ethash. I also would like to see, where in the code it is implemented in Go-Etherum. It would be appreciated if the link for that part of the code is attached with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The algorithm**

The algorithm is explained in detail, using (Python) pseudo-code, on the [Ethash wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash). There's also a related [Design Rationale page](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethash-Design-Rationale).

Those pages are nicely written, concise, and should cover everything you need to know, so I won't rehash them here. (Pun not intended, but I'll pretend it was.) Instead I'll concentrate on the code locations, below.

---

**The code**

The code is located in the [`consensus/ethash`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash) directory of the `go-ethereum` repository.

The main file you'll be interested in is [`ethash.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash/ethash.go). In here there are several places of interest.

- The [Ethash struct](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash/ethash.go#L325).
- The [`New()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash/ethash.go#L356) function...

Which does the following:

```
// New creates a full sized ethash PoW scheme.
func New(cachedir string, cachesinmem, cachesondisk int, dagdir string, dagsinmem, dagsondisk int) *Ethash {
```

- The [`dataset()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash/ethash.go#L491) function...

Which does the following:

```
// dataset tries to retrieve a mining dataset for the specified block number
// by first checking against a list of in-memory datasets, then against DAGs
// stored on disk, and finally generating one if none can be found.
func (ethash *Ethash) dataset(block uint64) []uint32 {
```

You can follow this final function further to calls to both [`memoryMapAndGenerate()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c7a4d9cf8ae307a94d16dd8197824eecd320cdf7/consensus/ethash/ethash.go#L107) and the passed in `generator()` function.

---

**Edit:**

And the part of the code that actually ties the two sections, above, together - and makes my answer an actual answer, rather than two slightly disjointed paragraphs - can be found in [`algorithm.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/algorithm.go). Credit goes to Péter, who actually knows what he's talking about. :-)

Comment: Here's the actual algorithm that generates the verification caches and the DAG https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/consensus/ethash/algorithm.go